# flutter Dismissible widget variable dependency

Tags: background, flutter, dismissible

**Edit: Fixed it.. Look down**

**Old problem:**

I am experimenting with the Dismissible widget.
I can successfully monitor the state of the direction, which is stored in directionVar.
It outputs something like `DismissDirection.endToStart`

I want to use this information, to change the placement of the icon that I show.
When removing an item, the background is red, with an icon on the right to it. Something in the style like Gmail.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        DismissDirection directionVar;
        return ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Dismissible(
              key: Key(products[index]['title']), //Should be unique.
              onDismissed: (DismissDirection direction) {
                directionVar = direction;
              },
```

My issue is this part:

```
              background: Container(
                 color: Colors.red,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.delete,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),);});}
```

I want this part to change dependent on the `directionVar` value.
The `padding` should change dependent on the value of `directionVar`, together with the `mainAxisAlignment`.

Something along these lines:

```
        if(directionVar == DismissDirection.endToStart){

        } else if (directionVar == DismissDirection.startToEnd){

        }
```

But I can't access the `background`: and `padding` property in these statements, since they are a property of the `Dismissible` widget and can't be changed inside `onDismissed(){}`

This seems like  simple problem but can't seem to solve it.

**Edit: Fixed it.. Very easy.. Just added this:**

```
   secondaryBackground: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.delete,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Have you tried to make your `directionVar` accessible for both widgets and then you can resolve dynamically the padding and mainAxisAlignment by calling `setState()` each time the direction changes.

Comment: I need a Stateful widget for that to work but I am working with a Stateless widget

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways that you can achieve this. For example, you can create a method that handles the direction dynamically and then update it accordingly in your widget tree. Something like

```
    List<dynamic> _resolveDirection(DismissDirection direction) {

    switch (direction) {
        case DismissDirection.endToStart:
          return [MainAxisAlignment.center, 20.0];
          break;
        case DismissDirection.startToEnd:
          return [MainAxisAlignment.start, 10.0];
          break;
        case DismissDirection.vertical:
          return [MainAxisAlignment.end, 5.0];
          break;
        // And so on...
        default:
          return [];
      }
    }
```

and then replace your tree with

```
 background: Container(
                 color: Colors.red,
                padding: _resolveDirection(directionVar)[1],
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: _resolveDirection(directionVar)[0],
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.delete,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),);});}
```

In the end, all you have to do everytime a swipe occurs, is just rebuild your tree with the direction updated

`setState(() => directionVar = direction);`

Comment: Interesting. I'll try this.

Comment: I fixed it in another way

Comment: Hey is it possible to implement the Dismissible functionality for an OnTap Gesture instead of Swipe?